# Determinación de clave-valor en metodo .map en Javascript

Tags: javascript

mi pregunta es la siguiente: dado el método .map a un array que contiene otros arrays, si por ejemplo cada elemento solo contiene strings, el key del metodo .map será el índice que corresponda a cada elemento?
y quedaria por ejemplo:

```
[
0:  ["Alice's House", "Bob's House"]
1:  ["Alice's House", "Cabin"]
2:  ["Alice's House", "Post Office"]
3:  ["Bob's House", "Town Hall"]
4:  ["Daria's House", "Ernie's House"]
5:  ["Daria's House", "Town Hall"]
6:  ["Ernie's House", "Grete's House"]
7:  ["Grete's House", "Farm"]
8:  ["Grete's House", "Shop"]
9:  ["Marketplace", "Farm"]
10: ["Marketplace", "Post Office"]
11: ["Marketplace", "Shop"]
12: ["Marketplace", "Town Hall"]
13: ["Shop", "Town Hall"]
]
```

Comment: La *callback* que recibe el método `map` recibirá tres argumentos: el elemento actual de la iteración, el índice y el *array* original. En el caso de un *array* de *arrays*, el primer argumento será un *array*. ¿Esa es la pregunta?

Comment: Y sobre todo, por qué no imprimes en consola cada variable y ves lo que contienen directamente? O lo miras en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map). Es mucho más rápido que preguntar y esperar a que alguien responda

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda!